# How to have a div size of the content in it

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin

I want to have div the size of the content, or the best, the size 500px by 380px, but it has to be on the center. When I make the div specific size it goes off the center.
What it looks right now without specific size:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6cxe.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1yR3.png

```css
.begin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #FDF8E6;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
}

.board-container {
  position: relative;
}

.board {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="start">Start</button>
    <button class="stop">Restart</button>
    <div class="stats">
      <div class="moves">0 moves</div>
      <div class="timer">time: 0 sec</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="board-container" data-dimension-width="4" data-dimension-height="3">
    <div class="board"></div>
    <div class="begin"></div>
    <div class="win"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css code right now (I've cut out some unnecessary properties that doesn't change the position or/and size of the div)

What I want to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KVdk.jpg

Thank you for all the help in advance :)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Below an initial setup using flexboxes.
You need to finetune the gaps, margins and paddings to your liking.

More information on flexbox can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.game {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: white;
}

.board-container {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.board-container>div {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="start">Start</button>
    <button class="stop">Restart</button>
    <div class="stats">
      <div class="moves">0 moves</div>
      <div class="timer">time: 0 sec</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="board-container">
    <div>Choose difficulty</div>
    <button>Easy</button>
    <button>Medium</button>
    <button>Hard</button>
  </div>
</div>
```